# Problem Using CATransitions to switch views

Tags: iphone, catransition

So I was attempting to use this code to switch between views:

```
CATransition *applicationLoadViewIn = [CATransition animation];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setDuration:1];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setType:kCATransitionReveal];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

    MyViewControllerClass *theControllerIAmSwitchingTo = [[MyViewControllerClass alloc] init];

    [[theControllerIAmSwitchingTo.view layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
```

But, the code doesn't work. There are no errors, and the code executes fine, but it just doesn't do anything. What do I have wrong here?

Comment: Are you testing it on simulator?

Comment: I have posted an answer please have a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the animation to the layer of parent view, then add the view as a subview of the parent view.

So instead of

```
[[theControllerIAmSwitchingTo.view layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
```

You need to use

```
[parentView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
[parentView addSubview:theControllerIAmSwitchingTo.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like:

```
 CATransition *applicationLoadViewIn = [CATransition animation];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setDuration:1];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setType:kCATransitionReveal];

    [applicationLoadViewIn setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];

    MyViewControllerClass *theControllerIAmSwitchingTo = [[MyViewControllerClass alloc] init];

    [[theControllerIAmSwitchingTo.view layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionReveal];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:theControllerIAmSwitchingTo animated:NO];
```

I noticed the problem is that you are not adding your view in your navigation stack and that is why your view does not get loaded and you see no animation.